# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-sdk-2.3

Failed to build flutter project

I pulled a codebase, injected all the dependencies, then I ran the flutter project

I expected the code to run normally, but I got the following error

"Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @1f991047

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
"

Android SDK is up to date, flutter, dart are all up-to-date, the build.gradle is all right, I really don't  know how to solve the error.
How do I go about it?